# Python - import helpers

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I import helpers in script.py ?

Python version : 3.6.8

directory structure :

```
main_folder
 |
 | folder1
 |  | folder2
 |  |  | script.py
 |
 | helpers.py
```

script.py :

```
from helpers import markdown
```

command :

```
python3 folder1/folder2/script.py
```

error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'
```

Comment: is there some files `__init__.py` somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following to the top of `script.py` to correctly set the path.

```py
import sys
import os

module_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

Keep the rest as is and it should work

Comment: That will only work if you execute the script from the main folder. Not a good general solution. Besides, messing with sys.path is hacky

Comment: Agree just mean to show what one could do to get the current project setup to work. I think that the real solution is to make a top level entry point to this package directly under the `main_folder`

Answer (score 1):

If you execute your script with `python3 folder1/folder2/script.py` then Python will not be aware of the package structure. The basis for imports will be `folder2` so it is not able to find your helper module. To fix this, use `python3 -m folder1.folder2.script` instead. This will let you import modules starting from `main_folder`.

Comment: How can I fix the structure and python able to find helpers  ?

Comment: @PiHPY You could have the entry point to your application in the main folder. From there you can access (import) all subfolders.